# I want to start a new django project with pycharm, but I can't find the function on it

Tags: python, django, pycharm

There are not have django choice, what should I do so start a django project?

[image: django project]

Answer (score 0):

I have the professional edition; the New Project dialog has the Django option second in the list.

[image: PyCharm New Project Dialog - Professional Edition]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is you PyCharm version, but probably you have the `Community Edition`, and this is also the reason of the problem. 
Look at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), as you can see, there are some restrictions for Community Edition, and creation of Django project is one of these.

So if you want fix this, you should update PyCharm.

Comment: Perfect, please if this is the correct answer mark as it. Thank you